Problem in send some Emoji to RavenDB via Python
When I use some Emoji like: "" in my strings and write it in RavenDB session, the emoji changes to something like "�" or "������".
I test and debug my code and the, The emojis are displayed correctly in the app and on the IDE terminal(pycharm), but there is a problem when displaying them in the ravendb database.
how can I fix this?

I am not a RavenDB expert, but I suppose that your problem is RavenDB encoding. Try to play around with utf-8 or unicode to get an understanding of what is going on.
